# WM_SYSCOMMAND dont work when child form is maximized

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a MDI aplication and a window procedure to handle formChild's messages. In this case, catch WM_SYSCOMMAND message to show a text. When form is minimized, show a message.

All works fine,...but

The problem is when child form is maximized and then I try minimized the form, the WM_SYSCOMMAND don't work, the `ShowMessage` don't show.

What message can I catch in this case?

```
//TCHild Form Child

function MDIChildProc(hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
var
  F: TChild;
begin
  F := TChild(FindControl(hwnd));
  begin
    case uMsg of
      WM_SYSCOMMAND:
      begin
        case wParam and $FFF0 of
          SC_MINIMIZE:
          begin
            {First Minimize then show text} 
            CallWindowProc(Pointer(F.Tag), hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);  
            ShowMessage('form minimized');
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    Result := CallWindowProc(Pointer(F.Tag), hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Exit your window procedure in the `SC_MINIMIZE` case, currently you're passing the message to `CallWindowProc` twice. Also use something like `OutputDebugString` for testing, a modal dialog (ShowMessage) might be affecting the behavior.